# Weird behavior of gcc while linking BLAS library

Tags: gcc

I have ATLAS library "libatlas.so" in an unstandard directory "/opt/apps/gcc4_7/atlas/3.10.2/lib/"

I put the path along with other search paths in environment variable

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/apps/gcc4_7/atlas/3.10.2/lib:and_others
```

Then link my code with it as follow:

```
g++ mycode.o -L$LD_LIBRARY_PATH -latlas
```

It then say "ld: cannot find -latlas"

But if I add the path again as follow:

```
g++ mycode.o -L$LD_LIBRARY_PATH -L/opt/apps/gcc4_7/atlas/3.10.2/lib/ -latlas
```

I have no issues.

I cannot think of any reasons this could happen. Is it because the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH has too many paths in it?

Comment: Please make absolutely sure LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set as you think it is set. Issue `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` immediately after the failing command and visually inspect the output.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes. I absolutely sure it is set. I did echo it out.

Comment: Please show your commands and their output exactly and with no editing whatsoever. Use copy and paste, do not retype anything.